# Disable Case sensitivity on Python's Webserver

Tags: python

To explain my Issue, basically my Dad teaches English and I just switched him over to linux, Everything works apart from a Teaching CD he uses.

I figured out shortly later that the CD was just a mess of flash files, and that putting it on a webserver meant I could use the CD without the official launcher (There is one for linux but it doesn't work)

So I ran this from the folder :

```
python3 -m http.server
```

And sure enough It loaded just fine, the issue is case sensitivity.

I don't know what the coder was doing, but in the SWF (it's flash), it calls all the XML files with the first letter capitalised, however the files themselves are not capitalised, therefore python's web server 404's due to the case).

I'd like to avoid having to change each file so **I was wondering if it were possible to tell python's webserver to ignore case entirely when processing requests ?**

I should probably note that I'm using python3

Any help is very much appreciated !

Comment: It'd be necessary to see the code to have a more in depth answer, but look up the docs on the `.lower()` function and use it in the `if` conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all files in the server root (including eventual subdirectories) are lower case, then it would be easiest to just override the `translate_path` method of `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` to unconditionally operate with lower case paths. Simple example:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

class LowerCaseRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def translate_path(self, path):
        # calls the original implementation and returns the result
        # converted to lower case
        return super().translate_path(path).lower()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), LowerCaseRequestHandler)
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.server_close()
```

Comment: Thankyou very much :) ! 
note : for anyone who uses this method, please note if there is a capitalised folder anywhere above your working folder then this will not work because the path will be ENTIRELY put into lower case.
(ex : /home/user/MyProject/html/index.html will become /home/user/myproject/html/index.html and 404 )